# Converting rectangular equation to polar equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I convert the following rectangular equation to a polar equation:

$$
(x- 3)^2 + (y+2)^2 = 1
$$

I was able to simplify it to the following:

$$
r^2 - 6r\cos(\theta) + 4r\sin(\theta) + 12 = 0
$$

but I am at a loss as to how to simplify further...
I'm trying to get r on one side and the answer on the other. In other words, r = ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? The solutions of you equations are just the points on the circle with radius $1$ around $p=(3,-2)$

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me.

Comment: I'm trying to have r on one side and everything else on the other. So, in other words, r = ?

Comment: @Jojo You cannot get it in that form unless you change coordinate systems so that the origin lies in the interior of the circle. Otherwise, there will exist values of $\theta$ for which there are two valid values of $r$ (i.e., a quadratic formula). You can verify this by drawing your circle and seeing that there exists radial lines from the origin that intersect it at two places.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 So the equation that I currently simplified the problem to is as far as I can go, correct?

Comment: Yes, unless you move the origin to another point such as $(3,-2)$, where $r$ would equal $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2 \theta$.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85 Okay, I see that now. Thank you!! :)

Comment: @Jojo $r=1$, see my first comment.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine $-6r\cos(\theta)+4r\sin(\theta)=2\sqrt{13}\sin(\theta-\arctan \frac 32)$   Whether that is a simplification I leave to you

Added:  from your edit, if you want $r=$ something, notice that you have a quadratic equation, so feed it to the quadratic formula.  $$r=(2 \sin \theta - 3 \cos \theta) \pm \sqrt{(2 \sin \theta - 3 \cos \theta)^2-12}$$

Answer (score 1):

$r^2- 6r cos(\theta)+ 4r sin(\theta)+ 12= 0$

$r^2- (6 cos(\theta)+ 4 sin(\theta))r+ 12= 0$
is a quadratic equation in r.  It can be solved using the **quadratic formula**.

$r= \frac{4 sin(\theta)- 6cos(\theta)\pm\sqrt{(4 sin(\theta)- 6 cos(\theta))- 48}}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

Given that you're trying to solve for $r$, threat the equation $r^2-6r\cos\theta+4r\sin\theta+12=0$ as a quadratic equation, where $r$ is the only variable and everything else is treated as constants.

But before we begin solving for $r$, it would be best to take the terms $-6r\cos\theta$ and $4r\sin\theta$ and factor out the $r$. This will help make the actual **solving** part a little easier.

$r^2-6r\cos\theta+4r\sin\theta+12=0$

$r^2+\left(4\sin\theta-6\cos\theta\right)r+12=0$

Note that in addition to factoring out $r$, I also reversed the order of the 2 terms so that the positive term is followed by the negative term, though this step isn't necessarily mandatory.

From here we can either use Completing the Square or Quadratic Formula to solve the equation for $r$. I'll be using Completing the Square.

$r^2+\left(4\sin\theta-6\cos\theta\right)r+12=0$

$r^2+\left(4\sin\theta-6\cos\theta\right)r=-12$

$r^2+\left(4\sin\theta-6\cos\theta\right)r+\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2=-12+\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2$

$\left(r+2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2=\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2-12$

$r+2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta=\pm\sqrt{\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2-12}$

$r=-2\sin\theta+3\cos\theta\pm\sqrt{\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2-12}$

$r=3\cos\theta-2\sin\theta\pm\sqrt{\left(2\sin\theta-3\cos\theta\right)^2-12}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

Make the following change of variables:

$$x = 3+r \cos\theta, \quad y = -2+r \sin \theta.$$

Cheers.